# Create mask for numpy array based on values' set membership

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I want to create a 'mask' index array for an array, based on whether the elements of that array are members of some set. What I want can be achieved as follows:

```
x = np.arange(20)
interesting_numbers = {1, 5, 7, 17, 18}
x_mask = np.array([xi in interesting_numbers for xi in x])
```

I'm wondering if there's a faster way to execute that last line. As it is, it builds a list in Python by repeatedly calling a `__contains__` method, then converts that list to a numpy array.

I want something like `x_mask = x[x in interesting_numbers]` but that's not valid syntax.

Comment: Would `x` always be a range array?

Comment: No, not always.

Comment: Would `x` always be sorted?

Comment: No, `x` is an arbitrary array. I am looking for a practical solution rather than algorithmic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `np.in1d`:

```
np.in1d(x, list(interesting_numbers))
#array([False,  True, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
#       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,
#        True, False], dtype=bool)
```

*Timing*, it is faster if the array `x` is large:

```
x = np.arange(10000)
interesting_numbers = {1, 5, 7, 17, 18}

%timeit np.in1d(x, list(interesting_numbers))
# 10000 loops, best of 3: 41.1 µs per loop

%timeit x_mask = np.array([xi in interesting_numbers for xi in x])
# 1000 loops, best of 3: 1.44 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. If there are no other better answers, I'll mark this one as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach with [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
def set_membership(x, interesting_numbers):
    b = np.sort(list(interesting_numbers))
    idx = np.searchsorted(b, x)
    idx[idx==b.size] = 0
    return b[idx] == x
```

Runtime test -

```
# Setup inputs with random numbers that are not necessarily sorted
In [353]: x = np.random.choice(100000, 10000, replace=0)

In [354]: interesting_numbers = set(np.random.choice(100000, 1000, replace=0))

In [355]: x_mask = np.array([xi in interesting_numbers for xi in x])

# Verify output with set_membership
In [356]: np.allclose(x_mask, set_membership(x, interesting_numbers))
Out[356]: True

# @Psidom's solution
In [357]: %timeit np.in1d(x, list(interesting_numbers))
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 ms per loop

In [358]: %timeit set_membership(x, interesting_numbers)
1000 loops, best of 3: 682 µs per loop
```

Comment: I'm surprised it is only so little better than the other solution.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Yeah with `searchsorted`, it seems that its sorting and then looking for indices. That `sorting` is killing it.